# Function init only if post_type is shop_order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying let the init function happens only if post_type is shop_order with the following code. My intention is to show the meta box to the admin order in edit mode / when create new order is clicked but with the following code in get_post_type is shop_order, the metabox didn't appear in the admin order edit view.

```
    if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
      exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    }

    class DM_Apply_Order_Discount {

      public function __construct()
      {
        $this->init();
      }

      public function init() {
      global $post;
      $postid = $post->ID;
      if( get_post_type($postid) === 'shop_order' ) {
        add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'add_apply_discount_container'));
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
    }}

      public function enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('hellodev-discount-manager-js', plugins_url('js/hellodev-discount-manager-apply-discount-min.js', DM_PLUGIN_FILE), array(), '1.0', false);
        wp_localize_script('hellodev-discount-manager-js',
        'hellodev_discount_manager_locales',
        array(
          'confirm_apply_discount' => __('Applying the discount will overwrite existing discounts. Do you want to continue?', 'hellodev-discount-manager-apply-discount'),
          'apply_success_message' => __('Saved with success.', 'hellodev-discount-manager-apply-discount'))
        );
      }

      public function add_apply_discount_container() {
        global $post_id;
        $order = new WC_Order($post_id);
        if (!$order->is_editable()) {
          return;
        }
        add_meta_box('hellodev-discount-manager-apply-discount-container', __('Apply discount to all items', 'hellodev-discount-manager-apply-discount'),
        array($this, 'create_apply_discount_container'), 'shop_order', 'side');
      }

      public function create_apply_discount_container() {
        ?>
        <ul id="hellodev-discount-manager-apply-discount" class="hellodev-discount-manager-apply-discount">
          <li>
            <input id="hellodev-discount-manager-apply-discount-percentage" type="number" name="discount" min="0" max="100" step="1"
            placeholder="<?php _e("Discount in percentage (%)", "hellodev-discount-manager-apply-discount") ?>" style="width: 100%"/>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <?php
      }
    }

    new DM_Apply_Order_Discount();
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Fixed with if (!$order->is_editable()) {
          return;
        } being removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with $post_id by use of global $post;

```
public function init() {
    global $post;
    $postid = $post->ID;   
    if( get_post_type( $postid ) === 'shop_order' ) {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_apply_discount_container' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks! But it didn't affect anything. Any idea? Im running on latest Woocommerce. Thank you.

Comment: can you add more code ? That helps to understand the code.

Comment: Added in the new edit. Thanks dinesh!